# digital filter and epoch length

Tags: filters, highpass-filter

A reviewer has asked me to re-filter my data to remove baseline drift.

Each sweep is 170ms sampled at 1000Hz and the reviewer wants it high-pass filtered at 0.5Hz.  The original bandpass settings on the hardware were 0.15 to 1000Hz

Although this is easy to code in matlab, the epoch is very short compared with the stop frequency.  How does the epoch length affect the filter order selection and is there any point attempting it at all?

Comment: this is the same as removing DC.  are you intending to filter each sweep separately?  why not just average the 170 samples and subtract that average from the 170 samples of each sweep?

Comment: Dear Robert, it was already band-pass filtered in the hardware so the dc should be already gone.  My question is with this epoch length whether there is any difference between 0.15 and 0.5 with a time domain filter.  There is not with a frequency domain filter as the lowest frequency is higher than both of these.